# Need help setting up permissions/security for users with Sprint Board and Wiki page access

Tags: azure, security, azure-devops, azure-functions

I'm trying to setup an Azure project page.  An issue that I am running into is that the users I have do not have access to do a lot of the maintanence related items on the Sprint Boards and they also do not have the ability to add/edit in the Wiki pages.  Some examples of things that users need on the sprint board are: adding new tags, and deleting work items.  I've tried granting access levels to all users both individually and under their team, but that doesn't seem to work.

I've even went as far as adding a user to the Project Admin group (which should give them full access) and they still cannot even add/edit a Wiki page or do any of the maintenance on the sprint board.  I'm the owner of the project and have all of this access.  What settings/permissions do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If users having the Contributors role in Azure DevOps Projects, then they can edit the wiki pages by default.

This Contributors group/role will provide write and read access to the repositories, pipelines, work tracking, etc.

Check the restrictions to the users and groups by going to this path and modify according to your requirement:

[image]

Refer to the [Azure DevOps Wiki Permissions Official Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/manage-readme-wiki-permissions?view=azure-devops) and this [AzureDevOps-Permissions&AccessLevelManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) for more information.